# Could not reach the remote Mailgun server

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

when I try to send an email with mailgun in laravel (i send by API not smtp) it gives me this error:

> Could not reach the remote Mailgun server.

Comment: Do you have a firewall in place? What laravel version are you using? Are you using a package or literally URL API? Is this happening on a production machine/dev machine? Is that machine in AWS/DigitalOcean/Azure? Add more info please

Comment: Mailgun requires you to whitelist your IP address to access its API. Did you do that?

Comment: @JLZenor I added my IP to the whitelist but it did not work

Comment: @matiaslauriti
   1-  I don't know
   2- version 10
   3- to be honest I don't know which I use
  4- dev machine
   5- no it wasn't in none of these

Answer (score 0):

This is a blog example to setup a mailing list, but maybe it could give you an idea of how to send an email.
https://fperdomo.dev/blog/how-to-set-up-a-mailing-list-with-laravel-statamic-and-mailgun
The setup is the same. The only difference is that I used this to send the email:

```
Mail::send('mail.contact', [
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'text' => $request->get('message'),
        ], function ($message) {
            $message->to($this->sendTo, 'Contact from Profile')
                    ->subject($this->subject);
            $message->from($this->from, 'Fermin web site');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that you added your IP to the whitelist but did you add the server's IP?

Your IP and your server's IP might not be the same.

Also, did you try to send this email via a simple command line (bash curl or equivalent)?

Comment: I added every single IP I found in ipconfig command  and I didn't try to send emails via command line  
anyway I tried to send an email by postmark and it gave me the same error

Comment: ipconfig gives you the IP of your computer. Does your code run on your computer or on a server?